# PyMongo find_one() returns nothing when passed _id as query parameter

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a single document in my Mongo database:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("569bbe3a65193cde93ce7092"), 
 "categories" : [{_id: 0, "category": "Groceries"},
                 {_id: 1, "category": "Bills"}, . . .]}
```

Using PyMongo in my project, I get this result calling `find_one()`:

```
x = db.collection.find_one({"_id": "ObjectId(\"569bbe3a65193cde93ce7092\")"})
print(x)
// None
```

Whenever I perform this same query in the Mongo shell, it returns my document. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is not working. Using `find({})` returns the document, so I know PyMongo can see it.

I can call `find_one({"categories": {"$exists": True}})` to retrieve the document, and since this will be the only document containing "categories", this will work; however, now I'm just baffled as to why accessing the document by `_id` is giving me such trouble. Neither escaping the quotes nor quote-wrapping `569bbe3a65193cde93ce7092` has made any difference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add to the @Simulant answer, you need to import the `ObjectId` from the `bson.objectid`:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

x = db.collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId("569bbe3a65193cde93ce7092")})
```

Comment: Ah, I think this is what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: `ObjectId` is in the `bson` module. So it should be `from bson import ObjectId`

Comment: @user3100115 not necessarily, see http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html#pymongo.objectid.ObjectId.

Comment: `from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId` -> ImportError: No module named objectid [3.5.1]

Answer (score 2):

pass it without the quotes on the content of `_id` you also need to import `ObjectId`.

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

{"_id": ObjectId("569bbe3a65193cde93ce7092")}
```

If you pass it with quotes you are searching for an Object with the String `ObjectId("569bbe3a65193cde93ce7092")` as ID. But in MongoDB the ID is an Object and not a String. Thats a difference.

Comment: I get 'ObjectId is undefined' if I remove the quotes